# Cell Only Show When Another Cell Has Contents

Tags: excel, invoice

Im using Microsoft Excel to make a simple invoice template. On this i have the columns for:

```
Product ID
Item Description
Qty
Price Each
Total Price
```

The problem that i have is when making a new template all the time i have to type in the formula every time to calculate the Total Price which is price each * qty.

How could i get this to be on the page all the time. For example when i make a new invoice i delete all the contents, and then enter new ones in but the formula gets deleted as well.

Another problem that i have is. On the invoice i also have a ticket for computer repair embedded, some times i have no items to charge the customer only ticket details.

Currently what i do is leave the first £0.00 in the total field then when i add more it works it out. Is there a way to hide the £0.00 until i enter something in the Item ID section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF statement for your total price formula. Assuming "qty" is in column C and "price each" in column D, enter this in cell total price (e.g. E2):

```
IF(AND(C2=0,D2=0),"",C2*D2)
```

This formula does the following:

- If both C2 and D2 are zero, the cell is displayed as empty
- Otherwise, the total price is calculated as C2*D2

This saves you deleting/re-entering the formula each time you create a new invoice.

Comment: Ok thanks but not sure where i put the if statement? Is it in the total cell?

Comment: Exactly. In the example above, that cell would have the value C2 * D2 or "" (nothing) in case C2 and D2 were empty.

Comment: ok thanks, now how would i get this formula to automatically carry on down to all the cells for example from C2 down to C20? Is is just a matter of clicking the end and dragging it down?

Comment: Yes, as with any other formula.